# Eigenvalues and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have found this one but do not got any clue how to solve it.

> Let be $A$ a symmetrical matrix $3X3$ with real numbers. Prove that if $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ are different eigenvalues with their own eigenvector $v_1\neq 0$ and $v_2\neq 0$. Then $v_1$ is orthogonal to $v_2$ from that show that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linear independences.

To me its pretty obvious the second part but I can not prove that $v_1$,$v_2$ are orthogonal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the inner product

$$
\langle A v_1 | v_2 \rangle = \lambda_1 \langle v_1 | v_2\rangle  \tag{1}
$$

But on the other hand

$$
\langle A v_1 | v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1 | A^T v_2 \rangle = \langle  v_1 | \lambda_2 v_2 \rangle = \lambda_2 \langle  v_1 | v_2 \rangle \tag{2}
$$

From (1) and (2) you get to the conclusion

$$
(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \langle v_1 | v_2 \rangle = 0
$$

Since the eigenvalues are different

$$
\langle  v_1 | v_2 \rangle = 0
$$

Comment: Is there a diference here using dot product?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, it is the same thing $\langle x | y \rangle = x \cdot y$

Comment: The main difference is people also use the inner product notation $\left<x\mid y\right>$ for inner product spaces where the inner product is not the dot product. Function spaces and complex numbers have different inner products. That's why I put a comment about real coefficients in my answer because you'd need $A^*=A$ instead of $A^T=A$ if you had complex coefficients and the usual complex inner product (conjugate transpose).

Comment: $A$ has real coefficients!

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want $A$ with real coefficients here.

Suppose $Av_1=\lambda_1v_1$ and $Av_2=\lambda_2v_2$ with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ and $A$ is symmetric $A^T=A$.

Then 
$$\lambda_1 v_1\cdot v_2= (Av_1)\cdot v_2 = (Av_1)^Tv_2=v_1A^Tv_2=v_1\cdot (Av_2) = \lambda_2 v_1\cdot v_2$$

Thus $\lambda_1 v_1\cdot v_2 = \lambda_2 v_1\cdot v_2$ if $v_1 \cdot v_2 \neq 0$ then you have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ a contradiction

Comment: I dont get the idea what does the contradiction mean?

Comment: A contradiction is when you have two properties that are both true but must have opposite truth values. Here we assumed $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$ and we conclude $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$. Those opposites so that's a contradiction. The conclusion is that if $v_1\cdot v_2 \neq 0$ then a contraction means that it must be true that $v_1\cdot v_2 =0$ because contradictions can't happen :)

Comment: ahhhh I got you mate, i did not see this part if  v1⋅v2≠0. Of course i know the meaning of a contradiction. Ok i got it thanks!